# XDocument throws error when particular node is empty

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Hi I have been using Xdoc to parse an xml .It works fine but throws error when a node is empty.How can we check for an empty node. EG: when the heard about tag has no value it throws an object reference not set to an instance of object error.

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Order")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           OrderID = item.Element("OrderID").Value,
                                           POnumber = item.Element("PurchaseNumber").Value,
                                           OrderDate = item.Element("DatePurchased").Value,
                                           source = item.Element("HearedAbout").Value
                                       }
```

i tried this but doesnot work

```
source = item.Element("HearedAbout").Value!=null?item.Element("HearedAbout").Value:"";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if `item.Element("HearedAbout")` returns null, then trying to use its `Value` property will indeed fail. The simplest approach is to cast it to `string` instead of using the `Value` property:

```
source = (string) item.Element("HearedAbout") ?? ""
```

The [explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx) will return `null` when the element reference itself is null - and then the null coalescing operator takes care of the default value you want.

Given the rest of the names of your elements, I'd consider using the explicit conversions for those too:

```
select new
{
   OrderID = (int) item.Element("OrderID"),
   POnumber = (int) item.Element("PurchaseNumber"),
   OrderDate = (DateTime) item.Element("DatePurchased"),
   Source = (string) item.Element("HearedAbout") ?? ""
}
```

(The two `int` values might be some other type - look at your data to work it out.)

Also note that I've changed `source` to `Source` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Check using the below menioned code

```
source = (string)item.Element("HearedAbout")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is that:

```
source = Convert.ToString(item.Element("HearedAbout"))
```